# Build CI/CD pipeline even if Spring Boot app event cannot send to datalake

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my spring boot app (new to spring boot), i need to make sure it can build in CI/CD pipeline even if we cannot send our event to the datalake (it may be down for example). However, i am totally oblivious as to how to do this. I know for a database we'd use the following, but for an event to go somewhere else i am unsure.

`datasource: continue-on-error: true`

The main issue is that it doesn't go directly to the Datalake(s3), but to another codebase that then sends it to the s3. Are there any annotations that can be used for a 503 exception to continue the build process?

We use a messagebroker to pass into another messagebroker in different codebase.

```
@Bean(name = "messageBrokerRestTemplate")
    public OAuth2RestTemplate messageBrokerRestTemplate(Oauth2ClientDetails resource) {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource);
    }
    
@Bean(name = "messageBrokerNamedParameterJdbcTemplate")
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate messageBrokerNamedParameterJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("rdsDatasource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
```

I'd post more code but its so big that i wouldn't even know where to begin!

Thanks:)

Comment: what build tool do you use?

Comment: I am using bamboo